# ConEmu/cygwin newlines don't perform carriage return functionality

Tags: terminal, cygwin, conemu, mintty

I upgraded Cygwin and now Bash is acting weird.  Newlines aren't always returning the cursor to the left side of the screen, but sometimes they do.  Here is what I'm experiencing:

```
$ echo hello
            hello
                 Thu Jan 30 08:31:33 :~
$ python3
         Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul 21 2019, 14:33:59)
[GCC 7.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 56+23
         79
           >>> 2+3
                  5
                   >>> exit()
                             Thu Jan 30 08:31:46 :~
$
```

I have `TERM=xterm-color`, and I've tried `TERM=cygwin` and just `TERM=` with no difference in behavior.

Another strange thing is that the less command will mess up the newlines when I first open a file, or page down with Ctrl-F, but if I page up or scroll up or down one line at a time, the formatting is fine.

ls -l works fine.  cat works fine.

Comment: hello @matt, has you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, I posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I've determined it's ConEmu.  It has something to do with my task command:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -new_console:P:"<Standard VGA>"
```

I use this so the background is black.  Also, when I logout, the tab closes instead of remaining open.

The default command doesn't have the newline problem, but has the problems stated above:

```
set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & set "PATH=%ConEmuDrive%\cygwin64\bin;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe -new_console:p %ConEmuDrive%\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -i -new_console:C:"%ConEmuDrive%\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico"
```

**Edit:** Of course, it has nothing to do with the `-new_console:P:"<Standard VGA>"` and everything to do with running bash with `%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe`.  I don't know what it does exactly - I need to look into it further.

**Edit #2:** It turns out there's an issue with arrow and delete keys being disabled by conemu-cyg-64.exe: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/2035.

**Edit #3:** Downloading the latest developer snapshot (which is 2020-01-31 at this time) of Cygwin at https://cygwin.com/snapshots/ fixed the problem with the arrow and delete keys for me.

```
$ unxz cygwin1-20200131.dll.xz
$ mv cygwin1-20200131.dll /bin/cygwin1.dll
```

Of course, that isn't going to work while Cygwin is running, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

For me updating to the latest ConEnum release (Version 1.3.18.1106) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Latest Cygwin release fixes this.

Comment: No it does not (as of 2021-05-31)

Comment: Even the latest dev-snapshot (2021-05-07) does not help.

Answer (score 0):

For me disabling "Inject ConEmuHk" helped.

[image]