# scanf() no carriage return after printf()

Tags: c, console, scanf, newline, conemu

I have the following code that reads 4 numbers from user input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NUMS 4

int main()
{
    int nums[MAX_NUMS];

    int i;
    int num;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUMS; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Enter a value between 1 and 9: ");
            scanf("%i",&num);
        }
        while(num > 9 || num < 1);

        nums[i] = num;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And when I run it, I get the following output:

```
user@USER:/cygdrive/d
$ ./test.exe
Enter a value between 1 and 9: 1
                                Enter a value between 1 and 9: 2
                                                                Enter a value between 1 and 9: 3
                                                                                                Enter a value between 1 and 9: 4
                                                                                                                                user@USER:/cygdrive/d
$
```

Why there is no carriage return when I press enter after entering the numbers? Am I missing something?

I am on cygwin:

```
user@USER:/cygdrive/d
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-9.3.0-2.x86_64/src/gcc-9.3.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-9.3.0-2.x86_64/src/gcc-9.3.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --enable-libada --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (GCC)
user@USER:/cygdrive/d
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 STEPAN 3.1.5(0.340/5/3) 2020-06-01 08:59 x86_64 Cygwin
user@USER:/cygdrive/d
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Comment: It looks like a terminal problem, what does the output of `printf("Hello\nWorld\n");` look like?

Comment: This isn't done by C, this is the terminal driver not going to the beginning of the line after you press Enter.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni \r just moves the carriage to the begining and when I enter a number it overrides existing output.

Comment: @Barmar so what can I do? I use ConEmu terminal

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, I don't use Windows or Cygwin.

Comment: @Stepii there maybe some settings for ConEmu, try playing around with them

Comment: @Barmar It has something to do with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987259/conemu-cygwin-newlines-dont-perform-carriage-return-functionality ?

Comment: @Stepii it looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987259/conemu-cygwin-newlines-dont-perform-carriage-return-functionality

Comment: @Jabberwocky no solution there either.

Comment: @Stepii you tried what the last very short answer suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in your specific environment the *Enter* key you press to confirm you input is interpreted as a raw `'\n'`. The original meaning of this character, in fact, is **line feed**, that means *"change line without performing a carriage return"* (`'\r'`).

In most terminals the enter key sums the effects of `\r` and `\n`, and this doesn't happen in your case.

To work it around try inserting manually a `'\r'` after the input insertion:

```
do
{
    printf("Enter a value between 1 and 9: ");
    scanf("%i",&num);
    printf("\r");
}
while(num > 9 || num < 1);
```

Comment: Working solution for my specific code. But still no solution to the problem with ConEmu.